# Does rooting android have any development advantages?

Tags: android

### Question

So my question is if there is any advantages and/or extra features that are only available to you if you root your device. If so what are they and what are their purpose/uses. I'm asking this question because as you all probably know there are apps that require you to have root for the app to function. So I thought maybe there were some development features that are unlocked when you root your android device.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rooting your device does not "unlock" any development features, although, it does allow you to have root access on your device you can make and test root apps.

I am not recommending you root your device, simply just answering your question.

So, no, it doesn't open up any extra features except for the benefit of having a rooted device that you can test apps that require root on.

Comment: Do you know why other app requires root then?

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper: Those apps are doing things that normally wouldn't be allowed by normal users.  For example, backing up app data requires root access because the Android system doesn't let apps read private data.  An app with root access can do pretty much anything it wants.  A rooted phone lets apps install themselves with root access to bypass security constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Tristan's answer is sufficient and all the development features are already available to you via *Developer options*, but I would like to add some points.

Rooted devices adds some small advantages over non rooted devices, I would list some I am familiar with.

- You can read Logs directly on your phone without connecting it to a PC. Apps like *Catlog* can be used for that.
- You can adjust the screen resolution and test your app accordingly, though it can be done using different emulators but testing on a physical device is certainly better if you don't own devices of various screen sizes.

If you've got a rooted device these feature are worth a try. If not, don't worry these features aren't worth enough to root for.

Comment: Good points! I was going to add a few but figured they didn't have much to do with the actual development standpoint. I didn't think about logs though! Good point.

Comment: I'd like to add that you could also install Wifi ADB, which would allow you to test your apps without connecting a wire. That IMO, is a huge plus for development.